# IMUL OllyDbg multiplication

Tags: assembly

I have problem to understand one of instruction in Assembly Language -> IMUL

From what I know, Imul is ->

```
imul dest, source1, source2
```

The problem that I have now, the result of multiplication of Imul in ollyDBG and mine is not same !

Here is IMUL on OllyDbg ->

[image]

[image]

And the result of the multiplication is 0x367AA048 or 914006088 in decimal..

I try to test with that multiplication with this PHP code..

```
echo dechex(0x00000053 * 0x97C9F598);
```

Surprisingly, the result of my PHP multiplication is not same from what OllyDbg get..

I hope someone can get me clear from this problem..

Thanks.

Comment: Trying using bcmul the bc math functions.. Yet you still have to consider the dec->hex conversion. Try manipulating your own dechex function using bc maths. Here's [the link](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of this multiplication does not fit into a 32-bit value, as a result the value you see in `EAX` is only the lower 4 bytes of the result.

Since this multiplication results in: `0x31367AA048`, the lower 4 bytes:`0x367AA048` are put into `EAX`, as you are seeing.